# How to get the x,y coordinates of a view in android?

Tags: android

I have used the following code to get the Location (x,y) coordinates of a view in my layout.I have a button and the following code to get its location on the scren.However it force closes the app when using this code.Also note that this statement has been called after    setContentView().Following is the code

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, button1.getTop(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And following is the Error:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(11630): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x196
```

.How do i get the view's (say a Button in my case) location on the screen(x,y coordinates)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the method you use expect integer values as references of `R.string.whatever`. Cast the getTop() return value to String should work.

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(button1.getTop()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

To get the x/y of the button (since API 11):

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, (int)button1.getX() + ":" + (int)button1.getY(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

[Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getX%28%29):

> The visual x position of this view, in pixels.

For API below 11 you are on the right way: `getTop()` is the equivalent of `getY()` but without a possible animation/translation. `getLeft()` is the quivalent of `getX()` with the same restriction.

Comment: But how do i get the x and y coordinates of that location?Currently it just returns me int value?

Comment: Thanks WareenFaith.For a detailed Explanation

Comment: @WarrenFaith in my case it returns zero :(

Comment: @milad.moafi which is possible. Is it top left positioned? What exactly returns zero? X? Y? Both?

Comment: @WarrenFaith No, It is positioned there but with 50dp Margin Top and Left, Yes Both of X and Y is Zero

Comment: @milad.moafi I am not sure if margin is considered by getX() and getY(). I would try to make a view in between and position your view without margins just to test if your values are still 0. Also possible that you are trying to get these values before the layout is measured and layouted completely. In this case (for a RelativeLayout at least) you probably will get the zero by default.

Comment: @WarrenFaith Actually i want to check my finger is hover my button or not, i have coordinates of my finger on screen, but not some buttons in my frameLayout

Answer (score 1):

**Precondition:** MyButton reference exists

```
AtomicInteger leftButton = new AtomicInteger();
myButton.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
    () -> {
        if (leftButton.get() == 0) {
            leftSubtitle.set(myButton.getLeft());

            //do something once you get the value..
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`button1.getTop()` returns a int number, `Toast.makeText()` treat that int number as a string resource id which is not existed in fact, so it crashes.

Try to use `button1.getTop() + ""` to change to a string.